# Proper variable initialization and call from another class

Tags: java, oop, object

I have these two examples below:

Example 1:

```
public class class1{
    private classN var1;
    public class1(param1) {
        var1 = new classN(param1); //here I initialize var1;
    }

    public void setVar1(param1){
        this.var1 = new classN(param1)
    }

    public classN getVar1(){
        return this.var1;
    }
}

public class class2{
    private class1 c1;
    public class2(param) {
        this.c1 = new class1(param);
    }

    public void handle(){
        c1.setVar1(sth);
    }
}
```

example 2:

```
public class class1{
    private classN var1; //var1 not initialized inside constructor
    public class1() {}

    public void setVar1(param1){
        this.var1 = new classN(param1);
    }

    public classN getVar1(){
        return this.var1;
    }
}

public class class2{
    private class1 c1;
    public class2() {
        this.c1 = new class1();
    }

    public void handle(){
        c1.setVar1(sth);
    }
}
```

I want to ask 2 things:

1. Are both examples equal?
2. Is var1 initialized in both two cases or I will get some kind of exception in example 2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried testing them? please do ;)

Comment: Compile it (I don't think it is). Run it. If you face exception, let us know. Sure we will help.

Comment: I get to both exmaples `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, both examples are not equal. In example one the variable is initialized at construction time and `class1` cannot be instantiated without it. In example 2, the variable is not initialized and is given the default value of `null` until it is set at some later time `setVar1`
2. No, you will not get an exception. If you try to call `getVar1` before you call `handle`, you will get the default `null` value.

Answer (score -1):

**Are both examples equal?**

No, In case -1 , `new class1(param);` initializes `var1;` ( to a non-null value), in second case, `var1` will be `null`.